# Should an unused audio input be left floating or connected to GND?

Tags: circuit-design, audio, signal

I am designing an audio circuit with multiple signal inputs through a jack connector that may not always be active simultaneously. In this case, is it better to connect them to GND when not in use to avoid signal interference?
In the case of the MP3 input below, connecting SN and TN to GND connects S and T to GND only when the jack is not connected.

[image]

Comment: Half-bias is another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jack inputs should have a DC path to ground (10k ohms typically). If you do that, you don't need to do anything with the switches.

If you still feel you need to use the switches (perhaps you have some hum pickup), use a resistance to GND (e.g., 1k) on each switch rather than tying directly to ground.

Comment: So a 10k pulldown? Which is the best solution between the 2 you proposed?

Comment: Could you add why it is preferable to use a 1k resistance to ground rather than typing it directly?  Would this still apply if it is a spare input which will never be used?

Comment: The resistor to the switch contact prevents the plug from being dead-shorted as it is inserted or pulled out.